# React Native app with react-hook-form not working (View config getter callback form component 'input' must be a function (received 'undefined')

Tags: react-native, react-hook-form

I'm creating a mobile app with React Native and I need to use a form. I want to use react-hook-form, but I can't get it to work, even in a newly created project. I did the following:

1. Created new React Native projects: it runs as it should
2. npm install react-hook-form
3. copy-paste following code to App.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

export default function App() {
  const { register, handleSubmit, watch, formState: { errors } } = useForm();
  const onSubmit = data => console.log(data);

  console.log(watch("example")); // watch input value by passing the name of it

  return (
    /* "handleSubmit" will validate your inputs before invoking "onSubmit" */
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      {/* register your input into the hook by invoking the "register" function */}
      <input defaultValue="test" {...register("example")} />
      
      {/* include validation with required or other standard HTML validation rules */}
      <input {...register("exampleRequired", { required: true })} />
      {/* errors will return when field validation fails  */}
      {errors.exampleRequired && <span>This field is required</span>}
      
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}
```

It gives following error: [screenshot of emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbV2V.png)
I have no idea what's the problem. Is there something wrong with the installation of react-hook-form as it doesn't recognize the input field?

Thanks!

Comment: hmm, dude are you sure its input and form with lowercase ?  React component should start with capitals tho

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized read this

Comment: I got the same error, input must be a function, received undefined, following this tutorial https://react-hook-form.com/get-started#Quickstart , did you find a solution to this?